# Simple closed curve of positive curvature that is stabilized under some rotation

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, plane-curves

Consider the following statement:

> Suppose that $C$ is a smooth simple closed curve in $\mathbb R^2$ with positive curvature. Let $O$ be the mass center of the region bound by $C$. If $C$ is invariant under the rotation on $\mathbb R^2$ by $\pi/2$ about $O$, then $C$ is a circle.

I obtain this statement by applying nontrivial results by Simon Brendle, regarding the existence of diffeomorphism between uniformly convex domains that satisfies certain conditions.
(Recall that the positivity of curvature implies that $C$ bounds a uniformly convex region.)

However, the statement looks so elementary, so I believe that some easier proof exists.
But I am not capable of coming up with one.
Could anyone help?

Notice that the positivity of curvature excludes curves like $x^4+y^4=1$, which seems to be a counterexample at first glance.

Comment: What result is that? Because I don’t think your statement is true.

Comment: But is that true? Take any square with "smoothed" corners, doesn't it meet the hypotheses of the theorem?

Comment: is a square with rounded corners not invariant under a rotation of $\pi/2$?

Comment: The curvature needs to be positive, so the curves cannot contain a line segment (and  curves like $x^4+y^4=1$ is neither a counterexample.)

Comment: Interesting question, point taken!

Comment: So now that you have a counterexample, do you see what the flaw is in your application of Brendle’s result?

Comment: @TedShifrin No, I am still struggling to find my mistakes. Maybe I will post that question for help, if I still cannot do it myself in the following few days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample. The curve defined by the cartesian equation
$$
x^4+y^4+x^2y^2=1
$$
has rotational symmetry of order $4$ and its curvature is always positive. Here's a plot of the curve:

[image]

And here's a plot ot the curvature as a function of polar angle:

[image]